# C# Mysql datagridview1.DataSource always throws null reference exception

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I am trying to read data from a mysql server.  The code works fine when I use an older project.  But I created a new one and a null reference is thrown every time I it gets to  datagridview1.DataSource = BindingSource.  and I get this error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
The code is very simple, and I have tired many different examples and still the same thing.

```
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from work", connection);
            MySqlDataAdapter workDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            workDA.SelectCommand = command;
            DataTable workDT = new DataTable();
            workDA.Fill(workDT);
            BindingSource workBS = new BindingSource();
            workBS.DataSource = workDT;
```

Exception here  DGWork.DataSource = workBS;
workDA.Update(workDT);

Comment: Can you use a debugger and check what variable is null? Check also the DGWork one

Comment: I created the DGV object at the begging of my code I listed and it worked.  But its not working where I can use it.  IT gets past the NULL exception error.  But no DGV is displayed.  I would simply like to reference the object from to DGV I dragged from tools to the form.  But that caused a null exception.  Almost like the object doesn't exist.